# Frechet derivative of "power function"

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with norm $\|\cdot\|$, and let $p\geq2.$ Define $F(x):=\|x\|^p,\,\forall x\in H.$

Now I want to calculate the first and second order Frechet derivatives of $F$.

When $p=2$, it is straightforward to check that $F^\prime(x)=2(x,\cdot)$ using the Hilbert structure, and it is reasonable to guess that $F^{\prime\prime}(x)=2$.

But when $p$ is other than $2$, the thing seems very different. I guess that
$$F^\prime(x)=p\|x\|^{p-2}(x,\cdot)$$
and
$$F^{\prime\prime}(x)=(p-1)p\|x\|^{p-3}(x,\cdot)$$
but I cannot check them.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have edited to modify the typos in the question.

Comment: Is $H$ a real Hilbert space?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the chain rule because $x\mapsto\|x\|^p$ is the composition of the mappings $x\mapsto\|x\|^2$ and $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^{\frac{p}{2}}$.

Comment: I have solved the problem with your help. Many thanks!